# how to using html tags on asp.net projects

Tags: html, asp.net, viewport

I am trying to use viewport on my asp.net project 
using this tag

```
<asp:HtmlMeta runat="server" ID="viewPort" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

I got this error

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request.
>
> Please review the following specific parse error details and modify
>   your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message:
>
> > Unknown server tag 'asp:HtmlMeta'.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Why would you need to access it anyway? But try `<meta runat="server" ID="viewPort"  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I need it to be able to run it on mobile devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that's not how [the `HtmlMeta` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlmeta) is intended to be used.

For starters, if you don't need programmatic access and just need a `<meta>` element, then just use one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

That is, unless you *need* to interact with this from your server-side code, there's no reason to overcomplicate it.  Just use the HTML normally.

On the other hand, if you *do* need programmatic access (such as to dynamically set the `content` based on some condition), you'd use the `HtmlMeta` class in your server-side code.  For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlMeta viewport = new HtmlMeta();
    viewport.Name = "viewport";
    viewport.Content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0";

    HtmlHead header = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
    header.Controls.Add(viewport);
}
```